# Thermal decomposition results: repeatable in ordinary temperatures?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, analytical-chemistry

In thermal decomposition studies where very high temperatures are used (see below for four reactions and their respective temperatures, coming from one paper), can I directly relate these decomposition processes to the ones that happen in room temperature?

Is it OK to assume those same reactions will take place even if those temperatures are not reached (instead taking more time to happen or with the requirement of other variables to compensate for the absence of the same heat, but still existing the same mechanism)?

> 117–170° C: $\ce{Cu(CH3COO)2·H2O → Cu(CH3COO)2}$
>
> 170–309° C: $\ce{Cu(CH3COO)2 → Cu2O}$
>
> 309–479° C: $\ce{Cu2O → CuO}$
>
> 946–1016° C: $\ce{CuO → Cu2O}$

Obs.: these reactions are neither complete nor balanced.